# Paypal c# REST API asks for an undocumented configuration section

Tags: c#, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm hacking hard at [Battle Hack London](http://battlehack.org/london/) and I've stumbled in an annoying problem. The PayPal SDK for c# doesn't seem to work quite right.

I'm trying to do my first transaction and here's my code (which I put together fixing the broken [online docs](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/):

```
var tokenCredential = new OAuthTokenCredential(something, someother);
var accessToken = tokenCredential.GetAccessToken();
Payment createdPayment = new Payment
{
  intent = "sale",
  transactions = new List<Transaction>
  {
    new Transaction
    {
      amount = new Amount
      {
        total = value.ToString("R"), 
        currency = "GBP"
      },
      description = forWhat
    }
  }
}.Create(accessToken);
```

This results in

> Cannot parse *.Config file. Ensure you have configured the 'paypal' section correctly.

which I've traced down to [this line of code](https://github.com/paypal/sdk-core-dotnet/blob/master/Source/SDK/Manager/ConfigManager.cs#L66) but I don't know how to configure that section correctly and I can't find the correct documentation.

How is tthe csharp REST SDK supposed to be configured?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've worked this out with the support of a PayPal dev. One needs to add:

```xml
<configSections>
  <section name="paypal" type="PayPal.Manager.SDKConfigHandler, PayPalCoreSDK"/>
</configSections>
<paypal>
  <accounts>
    <account apiUsername="xxx"
             apiPassword="yyy"
             applicationId="APP-80W284485P519543T"
             apiSignature="zzz"
             />
  </accounts>
  <settings>
    <add name="mode" value="sandbox"/>
  </settings>
</paypal>
```

where `xxx`, `yyy`, `zzz` you are values that you get from the "Account details" of your main [sandbox test account](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/accounts).

Comment: I'm trying to make this a desktop application without using any web.anything, really. If I have to parse a web page html code to make it happen that's fine, but my employer is switching from the Authorize.Net API to the Paypal API and I imagine it's about as complicated as dropping an electric engine into a diesel truck (coming from a guy who knows absolutely nothing about cars or trucks).

Comment: I did not have to include the <accounts> section, but I did have to include the <settings><add name="mode"> section even though I had set it in code via the config dictionary.

Answer (score 8):

I was running into this same error.  I tried Skliwz's solution but it did not work for me.

Instead I was able to get a result by passing a dictionary object with the call.

```
Dictionary<string, string> payPalConfig = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        payPalConfig.Add("mode", "sandbox");
OAuthTokenCredential tokenCredential = new AuthTokenCredential("myCliedId", "myClientSecret", payPalConfig);
string accessToken = tokenCredential.GetAccessToken();
```

Still working on get my Log In to work...

Comment: This allows the access token to be created, but nothing else works.  For example, calling something like Payment.Get(accessToken, paymentId) to get a payment results in the same error about the missing config section.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using PayPal .Net SDK (mine is version 1.3.0) you just need the following:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="paypal" type="PayPal.SDKConfigHandler, PayPal" />
</configSections>
<paypal>
    <settings>
       <add name="mode" value="sandbox" />
    </settings>
</paypal>
```

Comment: There's also [a section in the documentation on GitHub for the SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK#2-configure-your-application) that provides an example of what can go in the config.  One thing I would add to your config example here is the inclusion of the `clientId` and `clientSecret` settings for a PayPal REST app (with the values masked of course!).

Answer (score 1):

If you're like me, and don't want to store the client information in the *.config file (web.config, app.config) I've found you can specify it in a Dictionary which you have to pass-in to OAuthTokenCredential AND assigned to the APIContext.Config (key to working):

```
var clientId = "___REPLACE_WITH_CLIENTID___";
var clientSecret = "___REPLACE_WITH_CLIENTSECRET___";            
var sdkConfig = new Dictionary<string, string> {
   { "mode", "sandbox" },
   { "clientId", clientId },
   { "clientSecret", clientSecret }
};
var accessToken = new OAuthTokenCredential(clientId, clientSecret, sdkConfig).GetAccessToken();
var apiContext = new APIContext(accessToken);
apiContext.Config = sdkConfig;
```

Seems a bit redundant to have to pass it into OAuthTokenCredential and set it to apiContext.Config, but that's what works for me.

Comment: Adding the values to web.config was not an option for me, and this method worked.

Answer (score 0):

Just for future reference, the available config settings for the [PayPal .NET SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK) are now provided on the [SDK's GitHub wiki](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/wiki/Configuration).  This includes information on what all the supported PayPal config settings are and their default values.

The wiki also includes information on how to (optionally) [setup log4net](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/wiki/Configuration#log4net-config-settings-optional) in the config if you'd like to enable logging with your application.

If any information is missing or needs clarification, or if you'd like to request support for more config settings, please don't hesitate to let me know here or [on GitHub](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/wiki/Contributing-to-the-SDK).

Answer (score 0):

```
var config = ConfigManager.Instance.GetProperties();

        // Use OAuthTokenCredential to request an access token from PayPal
        var accessToken = new OAuthTokenCredential(config).GetAccessToken();
```

Web config:

```
    <configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="paypal" type="PayPal.SDKConfigHandler, PayPal" />
  </configSections>

  <!-- PayPal SDK settings -->
  <paypal>
    <settings>
      <add name="mode" value="sandbox"/>
      <add name="clientId" value="_client_Id_"/>
      <add name="clientSecret" value="_client_secret_"/>
    </settings>
  </paypal>
</configuration>
```