# Cannot parse *.Config file

Tags: winforms, api, config

In a .NET 4.5 Winforms app and using the exact code from the PayPal API doc I'm getting:

"Cannot parse *.Config file. Ensure you have configured the 'paypal' section correctly."

I'm just posting the line that causes this:
OAuthTokenCredential tokenCredential = new OAuthTokenCredential("xxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxx");

Any ideas how to proceed?

Thanks

Comment: That line isn't from your config file.

Comment: Correct. It is in my form code. Winforms App.

Comment: But the error says cannot parse a config file.   Doesn't it make sense to look there?

Comment: Steve, you're not helpful but thanks for trying.

Comment: I am being helpful.  You don't realize it yet....but you will.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Since Steve chose to be obtuse, for the sake if anyone else having this issue, here is the link to a similar question which solved my problem. Might be my lack of experience working with app.config files but I had to be sure to insert the code as the first entries in the file or my HttpClient class failed on startup.

Link that put me on the right path:
[Paypal c# REST API asks for an undocumented configuration section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19338986/paypal-c-sharp-rest-api-asks-for-an-undocumented-configuration-section)

My App.config file (basic App.config file from a new VS2013 WinForms project after adding the NuGet PayPal REST SDK Package and the parts from the solution from the link above)

As mentioned on the link as well, aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd are from your sandbox account profile.

```
<configSections>
    <section name="paypal" type="PayPal.Manager.SDKConfigHandler, PayPalCoreSDK"/>
</configSections>

<paypal>
    <accounts>
        <account  apiUsername="aaa"
                            apiPassword="bbb"
                applicationId="ccc"
                apiSignature="ddd"/>
    </accounts>
    <settings>
        <add name="mode" value="sandbox"/>
    </settings>
</paypal>

<startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
</startup>

<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```